# How to auto delete and recreate AWS transfer service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-transfer-family

I'm fairly new to AWS and I need to use the Transfer Family for sFTP to an S3 bucket. I'm surprised at how much it costs to keep up 24/7 and that there's no simple way to save money by turning it off when not needed, Amazon says "you must delete the server to stop being billed".

I need this service to run once per week (and eventually once per day) for a window of 1-2 hours at most. What's the best way to approach this? Can I delete it and recreate it using scripts for example?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest you get grip on CloudFormation stack and that is you key to automation.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use CloudFormation that can be deployed each time you need to recreate the service AWS Transfer Family for SFTP .
It takes like 5-10minutes to recreate everything back.

Also, if you want to enable password authentication you can use the following link as a tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/enable-password-authentication-for-aws-transfer-family-using-aws-secrets-manager-updated/

Good luck!

Comment: thats a good idea